# Accessing Page name / final part of URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, controller, routes, action

I would like access to the page name from within a page. For example if the page was "somesite/contact" I would like to get "contact". If it was "somesite/signup" I would get "signup" etc.

Obviously I could strip this out of the pages URL using request.fullpath and some RegeX, but there must be a more object-oriented way of getting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in the view, call `controller.action_name`. If you're in the controller, simply call `action_name`. This assumes a RESTful design.

Answer (score 1):

If you have good control over your URLs (meaning if you *know* what is the type of what is gonna be at the end of the url), you can use the `params` hash, the `:controller` and `:action` key may interest you.

Otherwise I suggest splitting the request.fullpath on '/' and taking the last elem.

Comment: Better to take `request.path`, because `fullpath` comes with query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.path it will give the entire data after that you can use split function and then you can save the values in different variable.Here I have used two variable .You can use more variable according to your needs
 **resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]**